# uploading photo to web service with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, post, alamofire

I want to upload a photo. I check Alamofire but all examples are with Json and encoded. I need to upload the photo which was taken with app and send it to webservice as a file. Also web service's responses are string. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, urlString, multipartFormData: {
        multipartFormData in
        if let _image = self.profilePic.image {
            if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image) {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "user_image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }
        }
        for (key, value) in userInfo {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }
        }, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

Where `self.profilePic.image` is your image.